# .NET How can I change position of a control in code behind?

Tags: .net, wpf

```
<Ellipse Canvas.Left="37" Canvas.Top="260">
```

I want to define the position of an ellipse in code behind relative to a Canvas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like this:

```
Canvas.SetLeft(someControl, 42);
```